# Displacement field: Why is the polarization added and not subtracted?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, polarization, displacement

I am studying the electric field $E$, polarization density $P$, and displacement field $D$, but I'm a little confused about the relation between the electric field, polarization and displacement field.

If we consider a parallel plate capacitor with a dielectric in between and apply a voltage across it, opposite charges will accumulate on the opposing plates. Furthermore, the atoms/molecules of the dielectric polarize, resulting in an E-field which opposes the applied E-field, as shown below. This effectively reduces the E-field across the capacitor. The direction of the polarization density is defined as from negative to positive, and thus points in the same direction as the E-field.

[image]

I have read that the displacement field $D$ is introduced to account for the polarization within materials. However, if we consider the equation:
$$D = \epsilon_0 E + P$$
we see that the polarization is added to the electric field. This is rather confusing as I would expect it to be subtracted to account for the fact that the electric field is reduced by the polarization of the material. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remember that these are vector quantities. So even if you’re adding them, they could be pointing in opposite directions

Comment: The electric field *is* reduced by the polarisation field. $\epsilon_0 \vec{E} = \vec{D} - \vec{P}$.  The D-field is unchanged if you introduce a dielectric to a disconnected capacitor. The E-field is reduced according to the equation above.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the replies! Just to make it clear, does it mean that if we consider the equation $D=\epsilon_0 E + P$, that the polarization ($P$) of the dielectric increases  as much as the electric field ($\epsilon_0 E$) decreases, so that the D-field is independent of the polarization of the dielectric?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the resolution to this is the following:

$\mathbf{P}$ points from the (-) to (+) bound charges in the material.  This is the reverse of what you might expect in terms of an electric field direction.  For additional details, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density#Relations_between_E,_D_and_P).

In the equation

$$
\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}
$$

$\mathbf{D}$ is not dependent on the polarization, only the free charges on the plates.  So, in the figure on the right above, the sum of the field arising from the free charges and the field due to the polarization (which points in the opposite direction) will lead to a reduced overall $\mathbf{E}$-field inside the material.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I still don't get it completely, unfortunately. You say the D-field is independent on the polarization according to: $D=\epsilon_0 E + P$. But this equation states that it is actually dependent on $P$, right? Otherwise, $P$ wouldn't be in the equation at all. Or does this mean that $P$ increases exactly as much as $\epsilon_0 E$ decreases, so that $D$ stays constant?